# How to set the timeout for sudo asking for password?

Tags: command-line

For example if i run `sudo apt-get install vlc`,it asks me to enter the `sudo` password.

If i not enter the password for `sudo` it `[sudo] password for avinash:` remains for longtime.

How do i set this sudo password waiting time?If this waiting time expires,it automatically shows `time expires`.Is that possible?

**Note:** I am not asking about how long `sudo` remembers the password([RootSudoTimeout - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout)).

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not directly possible from sudo itself, but it is possible with some hackish technique.

**sudo_timeout.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout=10 #seconds

set -m

echoerr() { echo "$@" 1>&2; }

keep_eye_on() {
    pid=$1
    time_passed=0
    while kill -0 $pid &> /dev/null; do
        sleep 1
        let time_passed=time_passed+1
        if [ $time_passed -ge $timeout ]; then
            echoerr "Timeout reached."
            kill -9 $pid
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echoerr "Please specify a process to run!" 
    exit 1
fi;

sudo $@ &
pid=$!

keep_eye_on $pid &
while true; do
    if kill -0 $pid &> /dev/null; then
        fg sudo > /dev/null; [ $? == 1 ] && break;
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

The `timeout` variable holds the timeout in seconds to wait prior killing the sudo process that is asking for password.

Usage:

```
./sudo_timeout.sh <command>
```

Example:

```
./sudo_timeout.sh ls -al
```

In case the timeout is reached you get:

```
alex@MaD-pc:~$ ./sudo_timeout.sh ls -al
[sudo] password for alex: Timeout reached.
./sudo_timeout.sh: line 34: 14583 Killed                  sudo $@
```

In case you type in your password prior the timeout, then the command executes normally.

Disclaimer: The above is tested with simple commands like `ls` and `nano`, both with and without arguments, but I cannot guarantee that it will work in every case because I haven't thoroughly tested it, it's just something I came up with.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: if you rename the script to `sudo` and place it in a directory which comes in PATH earlier than `/usr/bin` - for example, in `/home/avinash/bin` - then the script will effectively replace the standard `sudo` command. Exactly what you need, right?

Comment: You may as well make an alias in your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @Sergey this code is very good as long as it is run as it is shown. If you bring it in `PATH` and rename it as `sudo` it will call itself (as it is using `sudo` not `/usr/bin/sudo`) and you will have an infinite loop. Is it not so?

Comment: @souravc: Yes, but changing `sudo` invocation in the script to `/usr/bin/sudo` would solve the problem.

Comment: Caution: this script will kill your program after the timeout.  The timeout is not just applied to the password asking itself!!

Answer (score 5):

To change the timeout for the password prompt, you can edit `/etc/sudoers` (or `/etc/sudoers.d/passwd_timeout`) and add the line

```
Defaults passwd_timeout=10
```

or use another number than `10`.

From `man sudoers`:

```
 passwd_timeout    Number of minutes before the sudo password prompt times out, or 0 for
                   no timeout.  The timeout may include a fractional component if minute
                   granularity is insufficient, for example 2.5.  The default is 5.
```

Comment: OP says "Note: I am not asking about how long sudo remembers the password"

Comment: @KristopherIves Exactly!

Comment: @KristopherIves That would be `timestamp_timeout`: "Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask for a passwd again. The timeout may include a fractional component if minute granularity is insufficient, for example 2.5. The default is 5. Set this to 0 to always prompt for a password. If set to a value less than 0 the user's time stamp will not expire until the system is rebooted. This can be used to allow users to create or delete their own time stamps via “sudo -v” and “sudo -k” respectively."

Answer (score 3):

Easy using sudo's SUDO_ASKPASS feature.

Create this script sudo-askpass-timeout.sh somewhere:

```
#! /bin/bash -eu
# dash doesn't support read -s, so we use bash instead

# "read" will not reset the terminal echo mode if it is canceled. Let's save/restore the tty status.
stty_orig=`stty -g`
trap 'stty "$stty_orig"' EXIT

## Default timeout is 60 seconds.
if read -s -t ${READ_TIMEOUT:-60} -p "$*"
then
    echo "$REPLY"
else
    echo "Timeout" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Then, create a something like sudo-timeout.sh in the same directory:

```
#! /bin/bash -eux

## Syntax:  sudo-timeout.sh [-t timeout_in_seconds] <sudo arguments>
## Example:  sudo-timeout.sh -t 60 apt-get update

export SUDO_ASKPASS="$(dirname "$0")/sudo-askpass-timeout.sh"
export READ_TIMEOUT=60
if [ $# -ge 3  ] && [ "$1" = "-t" ]
then
        shift
        READ_TIMEOUT=$1
        shift
fi
exec sudo -A "$@"
```

Example:

```
sudo-timeout.sh apt-get update  ##Default: 60 second timeout
sudo-timeout.sh -t 30 apt-get update
```

Comment: Gravedigging... This is the correct answer !