# VM Worstation and Xubuntu 22.04.3 - Terminal Sleep Mode

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, password, timeout

I just installed VM Workstation and Xubuntu 22.04.3 today.
Have a question concerning the Terminal.
I noticed that there is a time limit before I'm required to reenter my password.
Is there a way to increase the time?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the timeout for sudo asking for password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401522/how-to-set-the-timeout-for-sudo-asking-for-password)  To go along with the most upvoted answer there, you can edit the `/etc/sudoers` file by running `sudo visudo` from a terminal window.